# Jquery UI progress-bar value using viewbag

Tags: jquery-ui, progress-bar, asp.net-mvc-5

My application is MVC 5, I am trying to set the value of the Progress bar using ViewBag.  I tried:

```
var progressvalue = '@(ViewBag.progress)';
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: progressvalue
        });
```

and

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: '@ViewBag.progress'
        });
```

Had no luck, the progress bar does not show the progress; would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
              value:    @ViewBag.progress
          });
```

It give a syntax error but works.